# PyQt5: Why does my GUI crash when I include QtCore.pyqtSlot() with combobox, but works without it?

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qcombobox

I'm developing a code to show different widgets that lie on top of each other, but show only one depending on QComboBox selection. I'm fairly new to Qt so I'm still trying to understand slots and signals, but I thought we are supposed to use them to pass events? I'm confused why it would work without this tag, but crash when you uncomment @QtCore.pyqtSlot() below.

Appreciate the help.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Window Settings
        self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h = 0, 0, 900, 600
        self.setGeometry(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)

        self.window = MainWindow(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)
        self.setWindowTitle("MY Gui")  # Window Title

        self.show()


class Analysis(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Analysis, self).__init__(parent)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        lay.addStretch()

        analysis_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Analysis Type")
        analysis_combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        analysis_combo.addItem("1")
        analysis_combo.addItem("2")

        analysis_combo.activated[str].connect(self.analysis_choice)

        hlay.addWidget(analysis_label)
        hlay.addWidget(analysis_combo)
    #
    # @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def analysis_choice(self, text):
        if text:
            print('hi')


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Initialize tabs
        tab_holder = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()  # Create tab holder
        tab_3 = Analysis()
        tab_holder.addTab(tab_3, "Analysis")
        layout.addWidget(tab_holder)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Change it to `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)`. Take a look at [this](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator)

Comment: Or add `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)` over `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()`, PyQt supports the multi-signature in the slots

Comment: My bad, I must have passed over that during my search as it has been marked as duplicate. Regardless, thank you as this has solved my problem.